# SQL query with a self join

Tags: sql, self-join

I have a table something like

```
create table test (
id [varchar](3),
var1 [varchar](2))

insert into test values (001, 'X1')
insert into test values (001, 'X2')
insert into test values (002, 'X3')
insert into test values (002, 'X4')
insert into test values (003, 'X5')
insert into test values (003, 'X6')
```

Please note that var1 is some string and cannot be sorted.

i need to run a query that gives me results as

```
id    var1       var2
 1     X1         X2
 2     X3         X4
 3     X5         X6
```

i try this query

```
select distinct a.id, a.var1 as var1, b.var1 as var2 from test a join test b 
on a.id = b.id where a.var1 <> b.var1 order by a.id
```

but this gives me

```
id    var1       var2
 1     X1         X2
 1     X2         X1
 2     X3         X4
 2     X4         X3
 3     X5         X6
 3     X6         X5
```

can someone help me with this query to get the desired results?

thanks

Comment: You are obviously using a strange DBMS when it is not able to sort varchar data. I've never heard of any not being able to do this. Which DBMS is it? SQL questions should always be tagged with the DBMS, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
select distinct a.id, a.var1 as var1, b.var1 as var2 from test a join test b 
on a.id = b.id where a.var1 < b.var1 order by a.id
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that var1 is some string and cannot be sorted or have mathematical function applied to it. I have edited my post to make this clear.

Answer (score 3):

How about using `min()` and `max()`:

```
select id, min(var1), max(var1)
from t
group by id;
```

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no ordering to your rows.  You might as well put them in an ordering specified by `min()` and `max()`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that var1 is some string and cannot be sorted or have mathematical function applied to it.

Comment: @ManojAgrawal . . . I don't understand your point.  `min()` and `max()` work on strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT test.ID, Max(test.var1) AS var1, Min(test.var1) AS var2
FROM test
GROUP BY test.ID;
UNION ALL
SELECT test.ID, Min(test.var1) AS var1, Max(test.var1) AS var2
FROM test
GROUP BY test.ID
Order By test.ID;
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that var1 is some string and cannot be sorted or have mathematical function applied to it. I have edited my post to make this clear.

Comment: You cannot sort a string?  That's a new one.